# Javascript for like button applies for only first button

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying making app similar to twitter in which I want to give user to ability to like the posts. but only first post works neatly.

**HTML**

```
{% if request.user in post.userl.all %}
            <a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:red">&hearts;</span></a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:grey">&hearts;</span></a>
            {% endif %}
```

**JavaScript**

```
    document.querySelector('.likeu1').addEventListener('click', change_like);
})
function change_like(){
    m = this.style.color;
    if (m=='red'){
        this.style.color = 'grey';
    }
    else{
        this.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.likeu1')` returns exactly one, the first, such element - look into `document.querySelectorAll('.likeu1').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', change_like));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its not currently working is because you are using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method which only return the first found element in `DOM`.

In addition you do **not** need to use a **separate function** like `change_like` to handle your style changes. Ideally less lines of code is always better. You can all in the event listener

You can use `querySelectorAll` method along with `forEach` loop to get all the elements with same class as `.likeu1` and then add an `addEventListener` on them individually to check for style.

The [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method return a node list (Array type) is what you need to do.

Also to get the correct `element` we can use [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) and get the `style` of the `element` and apply `styles` accordingly.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
let getHearts = document.querySelectorAll('.likeu1') //get all elements

getHearts.forEach(function(span) {
  span.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.style.color == 'red') {
      e.target.style.color = 'grey';
    } else {
      e.target.style.color = 'red';
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:red">&hearts;</span></a>
<a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:grey">&hearts;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` only returns the first element that matches the `.likeu1` class - that's why your first "heart" works but the other doesn't.

All you need to change is `querySelector` - instead use `querySelectorAll` to get all matches, then loop through these using to add the listener. Your function can stay the same.

**Working example:** with comments on the code you need to change

```js
// Get ALL elements with the likeu1 class 
var allLikeItems = document.querySelectorAll(".likeu1");

// Loop through the elements and add your listener
allLikeItems.forEach(function(likeItem) {
  likeItem.addEventListener('click', change_like);
});

// Your function can stay unchanged
function change_like() {
  m = this.style.color;
  if (m == 'red') {
    this.style.color = 'grey';
  } else {
    this.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:red">&hearts;</span></a>

<a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:grey">&hearts;</span></a>
```

**References:**

- [Mozilla MDN documentation for querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Mozilla MDN documentation for querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)